# Query Builder Error in doctrine symfony using where in

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder, doctrine-query

I have a raw query which I would like to convert into doctrine ORM. It's basically a query which contains sub query to calculate total count.

```
SELECT Count(*) AS total_count 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   content_item_languages 
        WHERE  default_content_item_id IN (SELECT id AS default_content_item_id 
               FROM   content_item 
               WHERE  content_type = 1 
                      AND is_translated = 0 
                      AND modified_on >= 
                          '$timePeriodStart' 
                      AND is_active = 1) 
           AND language_id = '$language') AS t
```

I have written below doctrine ORM but still I am getting error

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$totalPostSubselect = $em->addSelect('c.id AS defaultContentItemId')
                    ->from('AppBundle\Entity\ContentItem\ContentItem', 'c')
                    ->andWhere('c.contentType = 1')
                    ->andWhere('c.isTranslated = 0')
                    ->andWhere('c.modifiedOn >= :timeperiod')
                    ->andWhere('c.isActive = :status') 
                    ->setParameter('status', 1)
                    ->setParameter('timeperiod', $timePeriodStart)->getDQL();

 $em = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder(); 

 $defaultSubSelect = $em->addSelect(['*'])
                    ->from('AppBundle\Entity\ContentItem\ContentItemLanguages', 'cl')
                    ->andWhere("cl.defaultContentItemId IN ($totalPostSubselect)")
                    ->andWhere('cl.languageId = :language')
                    ->setParameter('subSelect', $totalPostSubselect)
                    ->setParameter('language', $language)->getDQL();



 $em = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();


 $mainQuerySelect = $em->addSelect(["count(*) as total_count"])
                       ->from("(".$defaultSubSelect.")", 'AS t')->getQuery();

 return $mainQuerySelect->getResult();
```

Here is the error I got

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException] [Syntax Error] line 0, col 13: Error: Expected Literal, got '*'


[Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]
    SELECT count(*) as total_count FROM (SELECT * FROM 
    AppBundle\Entity\ContentItem\ContentItemLanguages cl
       WHERE (
          cl.defaultContentItemId IN (SELECT c.id AS defaultContentItemId 
           FROM AppBundle\Entity\ContentItem\ContentItem c WHERE 
                c.contentType = 1 AND 
                c.isTranslated = 0 AND
                c.modifiedOn >= :timeperiod AND c.isActive = :status)) 
       AND cl.languageId = :language) AS t
```

can anyone suggest, in exactly where I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

In doctrine query language you can't `SELECT *`, instead you have to deal with objects. For your example something like:

```
$mainQuerySelect = $em->addSelect("count(t.id) as total_count")
                       ->from("(".$defaultSubSelect.")", 'AS t')->getQuery();
```

Comment: I updated my code. but now I am getting this error

       [Semantical Error] line 0, col 37 near '(SELECT id FROM': Error: Class '(' is not 
      defined.

Comment: [Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]
  SELECT count(id) as total_count FROM (SELECT id FROM AppBundle\Entity\ContentItem\ContentItemLanguages cl WHERE (cl
  .defaultContentItemId IN (SELECT c.id AS defaultContentItemId FROM AppBundle\Entity\ContentItem\ContentItem c WHERE
   c.contentType = 1 AND c.isTranslated = 0 AND c.modifiedOn >= :timeperiod AND c.isActive = :status)) AND cl.languag
  eId = :language) AS t